# ionic 3 page error related to app.componennt.ts

Tags: angular, ionic3

This is the error I get

[image]

I have added the login page link in `app.component.ts`
but during the build of the application, I get the following errors.

Comment: Have you added it to your `EntryComponents` in your `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: Search for all occurrences of another page that exists (and works) in your app like `HomePage` and make sure you added the `LoginPage` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Delete existing LoginPage, get the app working and then add page using cli

```
ionic g page login-page
```

Comment: but i posted the same query on ionic github page and as of version 3.5.0 app.module.ts has been removed by the ionic team

Comment: what is your issue number? Are you saying they removed app.module.ts? But everything is there in their conference demo app.

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply , the issue number is #2530